# Display ArrayList of Objects in JList

Tags: java, swing

[JPanel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oty0H.png)

I have the above JPanel I am working with. When the user clicks the button "Add a loan" I want them to be able to display the array of loans (objects) in the JList (block of white under "Loans").

The actionListener is below:

```
    addLoan.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Loan loan =
                    Calculator.createLoan(
                            Double.parseDouble(loanAmount.getText()),
                            Double.parseDouble(interestRate.getText()),
                            Double.parseDouble(term.getText()));
            Calculator.addALoan(loan);
        }
    });
```

When this button is clicked I want to display this method:

```
public static void printAllLoans() {
    for(int i = 0; i < loans.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Amount: " + loans.get(i).getAmount());
        System.out.println("InterestRate: " + loans.get(i).getInterestRate());
        System.out.println("Term: " + loans.get(i).getTerm());
    }
}
```

The method for Calculator.addALoan is as follows:

```
   public static void addALoan(Loan loan) {
        loans.add(loan);
    }
```

This adds a loan object to an ArrayList of objects:

```
Ex: Loan(loanAmount, interestRate, term)
public static ArrayList<Loan> loans = new ArrayList<Loan>();
```

I tried this:

```
DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(Calculator.loans.toArray());
showLoans.setModel(model);
```

Of course, this does not return what I would like since I'm trying to print ArrayList of objects.

I'm thinking maybe cell render would do it but not quite sure how to do it.

Comment: Show the code that relates to `Calculator.addALoan` - does this actually add the `loans` which I guess is a field?

Comment: Hi - added that.

Comment: This just adds the loan objects to an ArrayList

Comment: You would probably use a JTable to display data from a custom object. You can create a custom TableModel. See: [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) for a working example of how you can do this. Then the ArrayList just become the data for the model.

Comment: *"I'm thinking maybe.."* Think maybe to [edit] the above to 1) ask a question, and.. 2) include a [mre].